# roundabout in Jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery to animate images. But i am getting the following error

```
 TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function
```

My code is like as follows.

```
 <div class="gallery" > 
 <ul>
 <li><img src="/images/15-1368597729-csk12-600.jpg" alt="Test Image 1" width="320px" height="320px"  /> </li>

 <li><img src="/images/15-larry-page-300.jpg" alt="Test Image 1" width="320px" height="320px" /> </li>

 <li><img src="/images/16-1368691358-harbajan-singh-600.jpg" alt="Test Image 1" width="320px" height="320px"  /> </li>

 <li><img src="/images/16-uma-bharti-300.jpg" alt="Test Image 1" width="320px" height="320px"  /> </li>

 <li><img src="/images/Firefox_wallpaper.png" alt="Test Image 1" width="320px" height="320px"  /> </li>

 <li><img src="/images/empty_user.png" alt="Test Image 1" width="320px" height="320px"  /> </li>

</ul>

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.roundabout.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul").roundabout({
       shape: 'lazySusan'
 });

 });
 </script>
```

but it's throwing the following error.

TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function

Please help me to correct this. thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you checked if the roundabout script loads?

Comment: In chrome (my favorite) you can use e.g. the network section of developer tools, click the three lines icon > tools > Developer tools.

Comment: it's not loading..  $("ul").roundabout({ in this line it's throwing the error TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function

Answer (score 0):

i bet the path to the roundabout script is not correct... make sure the path is correct( i assume with you code it has to be in the same folder where this file is).

> TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function

this means the browser was not able to find a function called roundabout.. which means it is not loaded properly..

one way to check if it is loaded or not is to, view page soucre when you right click on the page... and click on the roundabout script link in the view source....other is to check your developer tools (chrome) or firbug(firefox) while page is loading.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  i have to add anything like this??

Comment: yes you have to... that is jquery script.. and it is needed for roaunabout to work... and make sure you are loading it before the roundabut js file

Comment: i am loading the two scripts which are mentioned in the question.then also it's not working

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but still some people (like me) might be benefited by my answer.  I had the same problem and I found that it was caused by loading some scripts twice.  I had the following lines in my file, but these files had already been loaded in an include file which was in my header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
```

I have no idea why this might cause the problem, but removing the above fixed it.